# Определение доступности Flash player в Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, flash-player

Как в Firefox определить доступность Flash Palyer.

Flash Player установлен но заблокирован на конкретной странице.

В такой ситуации основные браузеры выпиливают из window swfobject, а у firefox какое то свое видение этой ситуации swfobject доступен но swfку блочит.

Как это определить?

Comment: `console.log(navigator.plugins && navigator.plugins.length && navigator.mimeTypes && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'] && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'].enabledPlugin ? true : false);` что выводит в консоль и правильно ли?

Comment: firefox вне зависимости от доступности плагина на этот код всегда false

Comment: Смотрите это https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2016/navigator-plugins-and-mimetypes-are-now-unenumerable/ и вот это https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Plugins/Flash_Activation:_Browser_Comparison

Comment: @Visman т.е. правильно ли я понимаю что никак не определить что плагин флеша заболочен на ресурсе если он установлен?

Comment: Предлагается делать так, как указано во второй ссылке в разделе **Site Authoring Tips** и использовать параметр `callback` в `object` с флеш контентом.

Comment: Еще загляните в `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(navigator.plugins)` и `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(navigator.mimeTypes)` что видно.